# Why so many FeatureDetector and DescriptorExtractor are not supported in OpenCV Contrib Repo 3.0.0?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I just compiled the OpenCV 3.0.0 with extra modules from the [contrib repo release](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/releases).

Many Feature Detector and Descriptor Extractor are commented out as below:

[image]

[image]

I remember they are included in `OpenCV 2.4.10`. Why they are removed?

Answer (score 2):

most of them exist
some of the trasferred to xfeatures2d module
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/xfeatures2d

Comment: Thanks. But it seems it only generates python wrapper. Its `CMakeLists.txt` file says `WRAP python`.  How can I generate Java wrapper?